# constrain only top

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop

With no constraint I have the following issue:  The user is disabled from dragging if they drag the header above the top of the window.

Like this:

```
  ________
  |header|
__|______|_____
| |      |    |
| |______|    |
|             |
|             |
|_____________|
```

constrain:true is too limiting for my uses as drag-ability off the sides and bottom is required.  This applies to constrained as well because the window will not be able to be dragged off the sides.

Is there a way to prevent dragging off the top of the page only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try constrainHeader config. see if this is what you need.
 http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-constrainHeader

otherwise you are on your own to extend it to fit your use case.